# What layout should I use for chat history

Tags: java, swing, layout

[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

I want to make a chat history in java swing.

I have a JScrollPane. I append dinamic multiple JPanels in him.
I use BoxLayout but I have a problem:
- When appending the first JPanel it are height 100% of JScrollPane.
- When appending the second JPanel, both are height 50% of total JScrollPane.

I want to make each JPanel have fixed height (40px). 
What layout should I use or what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First off, I'd consider using a JList and not a grid of JPanels.
- Your JList cell may easily display what looks like a JPanel view by simply using the right renderer.
- And you'd lesson GUI override doing this.
- If you must use JPanels, I'd put them in a GridLayout or BoxLayout container  (JPanel)
- Add this container to a BorderLayout using container (JPanel), to its BorderLayout.PAGE_START position
- And then add this final container to the JScrollPane's viewport.

Comment: Thx. I used JList and I create an jpanel inside. I Follow this tutorial: [link](http://daltanstech.blogspot.ro/2012/04/creating-jpanel-inside-jlist.html)